# Why is my market order not going through when using the Coinbase API? I still see my funds in the USD wallet. Im sorry Im very new to this API

Tags: python, algorithm, pycharm, trading, coinbase-api

Here is my code. Im very sorry once again im new to this API and I was wondering my funds are still in the USD wallet when they should be in the BTC WALLET

```
import cbpro
import numpy
import time

apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
apiSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
passphrase = "xxxxxxx"

auth_client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(apiKey,apiSecret,passphrase)
currency = 'BTC-USD'
auth_client.place_market_order(product_id=currency, side='buy', funds='0.40')
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cbpro
import numpy
import time

apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
apiSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
passphrase = "xxxxxxx"

auth_client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(apiKey,apiSecret,passphrase)
currency = 'BTC-USD'
auth_client.buy(price='100.00', #USD
               size='0.01', #BTC
               order_type='limit',
               product_id='BTC-USD')
```

Would This Work???